# What am I missing with accessing custom globals in exec()?

Tags: python

With my project, I have small user-defined python programs stored in files that I need to have access to some variables in the main program - I am running these through `exec()` with a custom global list (to minimise the ability for malevolent code to function). However, whilst passing functions in this list seems to work, passing the main program's variables doesn't work.

Main program:

```
lessonCorrect = False
safeAccessForLessons = {'__builtins__':{}, 'print':print,
                        'lessonCorrect':lessonCorrect}

try:
    exec("""
print('Found!')
x = 3
y = 4
print(x,y,x+y,x*y)
global lessonCorrect
print(lessonCorrect)
lessonCorrect = True
print(lessonCorrect)""", safeAccessForLessons)
    print(lessonCorrect)
except:
    print("Blah")
    import sys
    print(sys.exc_info())
```

Output:

```
>>> checkLesson()
Found!
3 4 7 12
False #First print in file
True #Second print in file
False #Print in function
```

Expected Output:

```
>>> checkLesson()
Found!
3 4 7 12
<unimportant> #First print in file
True #Second print in file
True #Print in function
```

Comment: Heads up: [`exec` and `eval` are never truly safe](https://gist.github.com/Aran-Fey/2667cef9420e930e57d80187a76e35e4)

Comment: Also, I can't reproduce your output. I get `False, True, False` as expected. Please post a [mcve] - remove the code that reads text from a file, and put the content of the file into the code instead. In the end we should get the same output as you just by copying your code and executing it.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I'm aware that exec and eval are unsafe, thank you. And updating the example now.

Comment: While you're at it, you should also specify what output you expected. If you expect to get `False, True, True`, I have bad news.

Comment: That is indeed the output I expected, what's the issue with it?

Comment: See @Arthur's answer, he explains it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is not with `exec`, but rather with how you are accessing the `lessonCorrect` variable.

See this for instance:

```
lessonCorrect = False
safeAccessForLessons = {'lessonCorrect': lessonCorrect}
safeAccessForLessons['lessonCorrect'] = True
print('dict', safeAccessForLesssons)
print('var', lessonCorrect)
```

This will output:

```
dict {'lessonCorrect': True}
var False
```

And so, to get back to your code, here the `exec` call is modifying the `safeAccessForLessons` dict, but is never touching the lessonCorrect variable. So instead of doing `print(lessonCorrect)` in `checkLesson`, you can do `print(safeAccessForLesssons['lessonCorrect'])` and you will get what you want

Comment: This was the issue, as it turns out...thanks so much, all works right now.